# how to get week number starting from sunday till saturday by in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

how to add new column having week number i.e should consider sunday - saturday as 1 , next  sunday - saturday as 2 in an daywise data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the below solution what you were looking for Or was their more to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`Week([DateColumn])` will get you the respective week number. This resets for each year.